# SQL Query [Count the result of a query]

Tags: mysql, sql, elasticsearch

I am trying to send an SQL query in Elasticsearch, and I am not getting the result expected.
I wanna display the number of users that has more than 10 failed authentication, so I am using this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as result_count 
FROM (
SELECT user.name, COUNT(*) as result 
FROM "winlogbeat-*"  
WHERE event.category = 'authentication'  
AND event.action = 'logon-failed'
GROUP BY user.name
HAVING result > 10
)
```

I am getting a result like that:

```
|result_count|
|:----------:|
|     29     |
|     78     |
|     13     |
|------------|
```

The expected result that I am waiting is:

```
3
```

Could you please help me to understand what I am doing wrong to get this unexpected result !

Thanks :)

Comment: You query would return only one row in any SQL-compliant database.  It looks like only the subquery is getting executed.

Comment: but if I delete `SELECT COUNT(*) as result_count`, I get a different result, I get 2 columns (the user.name and result), so it's executing it :( !

Comment: So if I understand well, it's a problem in SQL of ELasticsearch, right ?

Comment: . . I doubt ElasticSearch folks think it is a "problem".  But if you are going to implement SQL, you really should implement something close to the language and an aggregation query with no `group by` always returning exactly one row is pretty fundamental.

Comment: I will try that , Thanks for your answers ^ ^